How do I make it so that an element does not affect the layout of other elements in Swift? (Akin to absolute positioning)
Without Description
With Description
I want to make it so that when I click on an egg, the Text element will show up. However, when the Text element doesn't show any text, I don't want the layout to move or shift. Currently, my elements are put in a VStack and I'm not quite sure how to proceed as I am still quite new to Swift. Thank you!
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  habit-hatchers
//
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit 
extension UIScrollView {  open override var clipsToBounds: Bool {   get { false }   set { }  } }

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fulfilled = 0
    @State var numOfEggs = 7
    @State var habitEggs: [HabitEggButton] = []
    @State var displayHabit = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            let chickenImageName = fulfilled == numOfEggs ? "chicken_in_egg" : "chicken_in_egg_sad"
        
            ZStack {
                // background color
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9294117647, green: 0.9294117647, blue: 0.9137254902, alpha: 1)).ignoresSafeArea()
                  
                VStack() {
                    HStack() {
                        // settings wheel
                        Spacer().frame(maxWidth: 300)
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Settings tapped")
                        }) {
                            Image("settings")
                                .resizable()
                                .background(Color.clear)
                                .frame(width: 37, height: 37)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    // main chicken
                    Image(chickenImageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
                    
                    
                    // habit egg buttons
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: -10) {
                            
                            // invisible placeholder egg if empty
                            if numOfEggs == 0 {
                                HabitEggButton(habitName: "MyHabit", clickable: false).opacity(0)
                            }
                            
                            // creates eggs
                            else {
                                ForEach(0..<numOfEggs) { _ in
                                    HabitEggButton(habitName: "MyHabit", clickable: true)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.offset(x: 25)
                    
                    if (displayHabit == "") {
                        Text("Drink Water").font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 26))
                    }
                }
                .offset(y: -80)
                
                
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

I tried changing the Z index and looking through the attributes of the Text component. I couldn't quite find a way to make it so that the layout doesn't move once the Text disappears.

If you do not want the view to move anything on appearing or disappearing, you can toggle its opacity instead of completely removing it.
So replacing this
if egg {
    Text("Egg")
}

with this
Text("Egg")
    .opacity(egg ? 1 : 0)

That should solve your problem. To answer your question directly however:
If you want the view to not take any place in the layout at all, you can set its size to 0 ( in a VStack: .frame(height: 0, alignment: .top) ).
However, a VStack will still have a default spacing unless you explicitly tell not to ( e.g VStack(spacing: 0) ), so the layout may still change. One way to solve this without affecting the rest of the layout is to wrap only 2 elements in a VStack with 0 spacing. :)
